# How do I see if thousands of URLs are active without a timeout using C#?

Tags: c#

My project is under .NET 4.5. My goal is simply getting the status code of about 7000 URLs and put the URL and status code in a table in the Database.

The code is running properly for most of the URLs (10% of them will time out), but it takes several hours (4-7h) to run.

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(originalURL);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.Timeout = 2000;

    _Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    int statusCode = -1;
    if (originalURL != destURL)
    {
        statusCode=GetDestinationURLStatusCode(destURL);
    }

    statusCode = (int)_Response.StatusCode;    
    _Response.Close();

    return statusCode;
}
catch(WebException webEx)
{
    int statusCode = 0;
    if(webEx.Status==WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        statusCode = (int)((HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response).StatusCode;             
    }

    _Response.Close();

    return statusCode; 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _Response.Close();
    return -1;
}
```

I've tried to set the Timeout smaller, for example, 500, for more than 80% of URLs, they will time out and I even couldn't have a chance to get a status code.

Is there a way that I can get status code faster without so much timeout?

Comment: [MSDN: How to: Make Multiple Web Requests in Parallel by Using Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh696703.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)? How do you cycle thru the URLs?

Comment: @thepirat000  thanks! Your link is very helpful!

Comment: @AlexK. Your link is very helpfu too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are running one URL at a time, which isn't very smart performance wise. It will take hours indeed before such processes finishes.

You can use async `Task`s to execute the actions in parallel (and possibly `Semaphone` for the throttling). You can find more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh696703.aspx) about it.

You can also put the above code in a [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) and run 64 at once:

```
Parallel.ForEach
    ( listOfUrls
    , new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 64 }
    , url =>
        {
            // do your thing
        }
    );
```

Comment: @Partrick, Thanks for your response. Yesterday I tested your solution, it works! I put my timeout to 15000 in order to retrieve more valid statuscode, and with your code, it takes only 20 minutes instead of 23h...
Thanks again!

Comment: @Partrick Hofman, Hello, I don't know if you can still see it, but, I'm having a problem  by using your code. Like I said, it runs really faster than before, but I got 50% timeout... no matter I set 15s or 30s for the value timeout, it doesn't change a lot for the result. I feel that inside Parallel.ForEach, it doesn't really take into account of the value TimeOut of web request